# Correctly divide a double to be able to get back the correct amount

Tags: java, types, floating-point, double, rounding

I have a input to a method that represents an amount of money, a total price of X items.
This can be an amount under a number of currencies and is represented by a `double`.
**Question:** I want to break this amount into the price for each of the X items. Considering that the amount itself is a `double` my concern is that if I simply do: `amount/X` I could get a number that `number*X` does not give me the `amount` exactly due to e.g. rounding. How can I do this correctly?
**Note:** Please give me help taking for granted that I can not change the `amount` to be something other than a `double`

Comment: You can convert the double to a `BigDecimal` and do the calculations with that.

Comment: @Kayaman: How do you think that will help?

Comment: @tmyklebu Well it'll allow you to do precise calculations. However if other parts expect a `double`, it just means that the code was broken to begin with. If you're dealing with money, you need to work with `BigDecimal` until you pretty print the result for a user (who most likely doesn't want to see values such as `10.000000000256`).

Comment: @Kayaman: BigDecimal can't represent rationals exactly.  It's still a floating-point format, and the pigeonhole principle still applies---there is still a BigDecimal f such that (1/f)*f != 1.  ("If you're dealing with money, you need to work with BigDecimal" is totally false, by the way; plenty of financial applications get by just fine using doubles.)

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, this is not possible in every case. Usually, when the total price is really the product of the single item price and a quantity, the resulting double will have enough precision to do this calculation. But generally you have to store both prices.

I implemented a whole ERP, and we also have a feature where the user can specify the total line amount directly, maybe to round the sum after discussing with a customer. And this makes it possible to sell 7 items for 1000$. Then there is no way to create a precise representation of a price for a single item. And therefore we also store the item price rounded (cut after 4 digits).

To come back to your answer: Depending on context you will need the total and single item amount later anyway, so just store both.

Comment: I don't have an issue keeping both. But showing a price in 4 digits (because only this way we can multiply to get back to the correct amount), was that an issue to your customer? I don't remember ever seeing prices with 4 digits after decimal

Comment: At least in my country prices for fuel are given in higher precision that useful. A litre costs e.g. 1,299EUR, and are rounded after multiplying with the amount of fuel loaded. This is obviously a scam, because 1,30 is the effective price. Nonetheless, a single item price can always have higher precision that the line item amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BigDecimal` class:

```
    double a=456.6556756;
    BigDecimal amount=BigDecimal.valueOf(a);
    BigDecimal priceOfEachItem=amount.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(8));   
    BigDecimal amountAgain=priceOfEachItem.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(8));
    System.out.println(amountAgain.doubleValue());
```

`Output:456.6556756`

As you can see you can get the exact original amount

Comment: Yes but what will happen if I convert the result back to double to pass to other functions?

Comment: @Jim You will have no problem at all. You can retrive the double value as: double value=amountAgain.doubleValue(); and pass it to other functions

Comment: But if you want a complete precision accuracy then you have to use BigDecimal in other functions too..

Comment: This division will only work for an exact multiple.  What if the per unit price is not a cent. BTW you can't have `$456.6556756`

Comment: The question asks for exact multiple as far as I can understand. :) I only wanted to show that BigDecimal preserves the precision with complete accuracy. Did not think about the currency aspect  :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by taking the single item price as double value which won't round off the value(Yes,you may limit the number of digits after decimal).

```
double totalPrice = 500.33;
int totalItems = 6;
double singleItemPrice = totalPrice/totalItems;
System.out.println("Single Item Price = " + singleItemPrice);
System.out.println("Total Price = " + (singleItemPrice * totalItems));
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
Double formatted = Double.parseDouble(df.format(singleItemPrice * totalItems)); 
System.out.println("Formatted Value = "formatted);
```

Output:

> Single Item Price = 83.38833333333334
>   Total Price = 500.33000000000004
>   Formatted Value = 500.33

Or use `BigDecimal` as mentioned by someone else(but maybe the above will have more precision, let us know about that):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

BigDecimal premium = BigDecimal.valueOf(1586.6d);
BigDecimal netToCompany = BigDecimal.valueOf(708.75d);
BigDecimal commission = premium.subtract(netToCompany);
System.out.println(commission + " = " + premium + " - " + netToCompany);
```

Output:

> 877.85 = 1586.6 - 708.75

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Yes but what will happen if I convert the result back to double to pass to other functions?

Answer (score -1):

You can use Math.round for rounding.  The problem you have is that you don't know what rounding for you `amount/X` you need.  This is a problem whether you use `double` or `BigDecimal`

You can do this

```
public static double round2(double d) {
    if (d < -Long.MAX_VALUE / 100 || d > Long.MAX_VALUE / 100)
        return d;
    return Math.round(d * 100) / 100.0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    double amount = 1000.00;
    int units = 9;
    System.out.println("amount: " + amount );
    System.out.println("units: " + units);
    double perUnit = amount / units;
    double amount2 = round2(perUnit * units);
    System.out.println("perUnit: " + perUnit);
    System.out.println("amount2: " + amount2);
}
```

prints

```
amount: 1000.0
units: 9
perUnit: 111.11111111111111
amount2: 1000.0
```